# After running a SQL query using the ansible mysql_query module, how do I extract the data returned?

Tags: mysql, ansible, ansible-module

I have a playbook that is retrieving data from a test database, but I am unable to figure out how to extract the rows returned from the database.

The whole purpose of the exercise is to pull the value from the KVP and add it to a report, so eventual the output would look similar to:

| datetime | hostname | server_status | server_type | associated_controller |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | ATT_DELL | UP | NODE | 123.456.78.901 |
| null | steve_ubuntu | UP | CONTROLLER | NOT APPLICABLE |

```
- name: Sample playbook
  gather_facts: True
  hosts: sql_server
  tasks:
    - name: Retrieve data from database
      tags: always
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_host: "{{ login_host }}"
        login_db: "{{ login_db }}"
        login_user: "{{ login_user }}"
        login_password: "{{ login_password }}"
        query: select * from test_db
      register: mysql_result

    - name: output query results
      tags: always
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop:  "{{ mysql_result.query_result }}"
```

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [server_name]

TASK [Pull data from database] *************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [server_name]

TASK [output query results] **************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [servername] => (item=[{u'datetime': None, u'hostname': u'steve_ubuntu', u'associated_controller': u'NOT APPLICABLE', u'server_type': u'controller', u'server_status': u'Up'}, {u'datetime': None, u'hostname': u'ATT_DELL', u'associated_controller': u'NOT APPLICABLE', u'server_type': u'controller', u'server_status': u'Up'}]) =>
  msg:
  - associated_controller: NOT APPLICABLE
    datetime: null
    hostname: steve_ubuntu
    server_status: Up
    server_type: controller
  - associated_controller: NOT APPLICABLE
    datetime: null
    hostname: ATT_DELL
    server_status: Up
    server_type: controller
```

I tried the following:

```
    - name: output query results
      tags: never
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item[0] }}"
      loop:  "{{ mysql_result.query_result | items2dict }}"
```

Which resulted in the following, but I need to loop through each list items, extracting the individual values from each kvp to be used in the report.

```
ok: [servername] => (item=[{u'datetime': None, u'hostname': u'steve_ubuntu', u'associated_controller': u'NOT APPLICABLE', u'server_type': u'controller', u'server_status': u'Up'}, {u'datetime': None, u'hostname': u'ATT_DELL', u'associated_controller': u'NOT APPLICABLE', u'server_type': u'controller', u'server_status': u'Up'}]) =>
  msg:
    associated_controller: NOT APPLICABLE
    datetime: null
    hostname: steve_ubuntu
    server_status: Up
    server_type: controller
```

I have tried so many other things like converting the list to a dictionary, but I received the error below. I need to keep the input dynamic, but I don't know how many items will be retrieved from the database.

fatal: [servername]: FAILED! =>
msg: 'Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ mysql_result.query_result | items2dict}}): list indices must be integers, not str'

I'm not just looking for an answer to my problem, but what fundamentals about ansible do I need to read through to better understand the fundamentals about the values returned and how to extract them? I've read through Ansible's online documentation, but that's not the best documentation for understanding their product.

Comment: This error ->  list indices must be integers, not str, why not convert the data type to INTEGER type first and then it can handle them.  In other words, x = 1 is not the same as x = "1", or plainly the value of 1 and the word "1" are two different data types.

Comment: I can't really answer your question because I'm clearly not understanding what is going on with the returned data. The data is returned data is: kvp1: some_value <new line> kvp2: some_value, etc. So, what I am expecting is that converting to a dictionary would automatically recognize the kvp and allow me to reference using dot notation or referencing the key. Basically, there are no numerical values to convert unless they are implicitly applied and I don't know how to reference them.

Comment: Ok so when you converted it to a dictionary, each thing was given an index value, probably the order they were listed.  You then use that number to look them up instead of the word, and this allows you to loop from 1 to last thing using the number values.  The error message seems to indicate it was passed word "str/string" instead of the number value it wanted from the dictionary.  You said reference the key, and I bet the key is excepting to be a number.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) templates. For example, given the data

```yaml
  mysql_result:
    query_result:
      - - associated_controller: NOT APPLICABLE
          datetime: null
          hostname: steve_ubuntu
          server_status: Up
          server_type: controller
        - associated_controller: NOT APPLICABLE
          datetime: null
          hostname: ATT_DELL
          server_status: Up
          server_type: controller
```

declare the keys

```yaml
  qr_keys:
    - - - datetime
        - hostname
        - server_status
        - server_type
        - associated_controller
```

---

Note: You can get the keys dynamically if you accept the order

```yaml
  qr_keys: "{{ mysql_result.query_result|
               map('json_query', '[].keys(@)') }}"
```

---

Decide the format you'd like to store the data and create the template. For example, try CSV

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for query in mysql_result.query_result %}
          {% set keys=qr_keys[loop.index0][0] %}
          {{ keys|join(';') }}
          {% for i in query %}
          {% for key in keys %}
          {{ i[key]|d('null', true) }}{% if not loop.last %};{% endif %}{% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    datetime;hostname;server_status;server_type;associated_controller
    null;steve_ubuntu;Up;controller;NOT APPLICABLE
    null;ATT_DELL;Up;controller;NOT APPLICABLE
```

If this is what you want create the file(s) on the controller

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/query_result-{{ inventory_hostname }}.csv"
        content: |
          {% for query in mysql_result.query_result %}
          {% set keys=qr_keys[loop.index0][0] %}
          {{ keys|join(';') }}
          {% for i in query %}
          {% for key in keys %}
          {{ i[key]|d('null', true) }}{% if not loop.last %};{% endif %}{% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

will create the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/query_result-sql_server.csv 
datetime;hostname;server_status;server_type;associated_controller
null;steve_ubuntu;Up;controller;NOT APPLICABLE
null;ATT_DELL;Up;controller;NOT APPLICABLE
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: sql_server

  vars:

    mysql_result:
      query_result:
        - - associated_controller: NOT APPLICABLE
            datetime: null
            hostname: steve_ubuntu
            server_status: Up
            server_type: controller
          - associated_controller: NOT APPLICABLE
            datetime: null
            hostname: ATT_DELL
            server_status: Up
            server_type: controller

    qr_keys:
      - - - datetime
          - hostname
          - server_status
          - server_type
          - associated_controller
    # qr_keys: "{{ mysql_result.query_result|
    #              map('json_query', '[].keys(@)') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ mysql_result.query_result }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item|json_query('[].hostname') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for query in mysql_result.query_result %}
          {% set keys=qr_keys[loop.index0][0] %}
          {{ keys|join(';') }}
          {% for i in query %}
          {% for key in keys %}
          {{ i[key]|d('null', true) }}{% if not loop.last %};{% endif %}{% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

    - copy:
        dest: "/tmp/query_result-{{ inventory_hostname }}.csv"
        content: |
          {% for query in mysql_result.query_result %}
          {% set keys=qr_keys[loop.index0][0] %}
          {{ keys|join(';') }}
          {% for i in query %}
          {% for key in keys %}
          {{ i[key]|d('null', true) }}{% if not loop.last %};{% endif %}{% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
```